# Link element with text, background, display behaviour

Tags: javascript, css, hyperlink, background

So, this one has me a little perplexed. I'm probably just looking at it from the wrong angle, I'm not sure. Anyhow, here goes:

I have a navigation section on a site, and I want each button (links to define contents of an `iframe` below) to have one background image when 'normal', one when the cursor is hovered over, and one while its corresponding content is displayed in the `iframe`. I'm guessing that last one might require some Javascript, but I really don't know (all this is still relatively new to me). I'm hoping at least some of it can be done in the usual `a:link`, `a:hover`, etc. way.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to it when it's clicked and has the iframe's content changed like this (javascript):

```
function changeIFrame(link) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].src = link.href;
    link.className = 'activeFrame';
}
```

html:

```
<a href="nameOfUrl.html" onclick="changeIFrame(this); return false;">link text</a>
```

css:

```
.activeFrame { background-color: blue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new CSS class called "current" and apply that class to link that has its corresponding content shown.  All others don't get "current" applied to it.